# spring sftp read and write in remote without local directory

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, sftp, spring-integration-sftp

I know how to read and write from SFTP location with spring-integration-sftp with below configuration:

```
<bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory"
    p:host="${host}"
    p:port="${port}"
    p:user="${username}"
    p:password="${password}"
    p:allowUnknownKeys="true" />

<int:channel id="sftpChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter
    id="sftpInboundAdapter"
    channel="sftpChannel"
    session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
    remote-directory="${remote.dir}"
    local-directory="${local.dir}"      <-- i don't want
    auto-create-local-directory="false"
    delete-remote-files="false"
    filename-pattern="*.TXT"            <-- how to specify multiple type
    local-filter="acceptOnceFilter">
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="acceptOnceFilter"
  class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter"/>

<int:poller default="true" fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="100" />  

<int:service-activator input-channel="sftpChannel" ref="stringHandler" method="handleMessage"/>

<bean id="stringHandler" class="com.core.sftp.StringHandler"/>
```

I tried by removing the tag *local-directory* element but spring not allowing to do that, Is there a way to read and write the file without creating it in local directory?

Is there a way to specify multiple file extension types without case sensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an outbound gateway (`get` command with `-stream` option) to get the remote file as an `InputStream`.

Note that you are responsible for closing the session once you have read the file contents from the stream.

[See the documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway).

For a case-insensitive match on the file inbound adapter, use a regex instead of a simple pattern: `filename-regex="(?i).*\.txt"`.

There's no pattern matching with the outbound gateway; you have to use the `ls` command to list the files and fetch the ones you want. The [sftp sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/sftp) shows how to do that.

Comment: Thank you Gary Russel. is there any tutorial link or example for read remote file as stream and write file to remote from InputStream?

Comment: Not that I am aware of; but it's quite simple; the documentation link I referred you to has an example of using a file splitter to read from the input stream and emit each line of a text file, then finally closing the session. It really depends on what you want to do with the data how you would handle it.